# How to implement SpringRetry

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 classes.One is Msgcontroller.java and other class is RetryProcess.java

In Msgcontroller.java,I am using the following method

```
public String getSampleService() throws IOException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, HttpException {
        // Read from request

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String data = buffer.toString();
        StringRequestEntity requestEntity = null;
        StringBuffer eventResponse = new StringBuffer();
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        int statusCode;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String jsonReceive = null;
        logger.info("RequestJson" + data);
        baseServiceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/oif";

        apiServiceUrl = "/services/rest/item";

        requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(data, MEDIA_TYPE, FORMAT);
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(baseServiceUrl + apiServiceUrl);
        postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
        statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        logger.info("Status code from item service call" + statusCode);
        inputStream = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
        if (null != inputStream) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, FORMAT));
            for (line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                eventResponse = eventResponse.append(line);
            }
        }
        jsonReceive = eventResponse.toString();
        logger.info("JsonReceive" + jsonReceive);
        return jsonReceive;
    }
```

And in RetryProcess.java

```
public class RetryProcess {
    private static final Logger logger  = LogManager.getLogger(RetryProcess.class);
@Retryable(
        value={Exception.class},
        maxAttempts=2,
        backoff=@Backoff(delay=5000)
        )
public void getSplSevice() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, HttpException, IOException{
    Msgcontroller msg=new Msgcontroller ();
    logger.info("Retryprocess");
    msg.getSampleService();
}
}
```

But when an exception occurs in getSampleService() in MsgController ,RetryProcess.java not working.Can anyone help me

Comment: please share the maven dependency you have used in the project, Also if it's a spring boot project then why are you not tuning spring bean and creating an object manually.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @Retryable is expecting an instance Exception.class check what expectation you are getting and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@Recover` which is a fallback method if the @Retrayble throws an exception. In this case, you can use another method with `@Recover` annotation with the exception details. The method structure is given below.

```
@Recover
    void recover(Exception e, String someParams) {
... other code
}
```

For more details, you can check this link. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: @Recover
public String recover(Exception e){
 System.out.println("Recover Method--Exception");
 return "Recover Method--Exception";
 
}

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: yes..response of my second API is classclastException..I got that error